# PyCharm: Search+Replace and insert Regex Groups

Tags: python, regex, pycharm

I want to Search+Replace and insert a regex group with PyCharm.

Text I want to replace:

```
Utils.data_home(.*(lib|bin|src|apps))
```

Insert

```
Utils.src_home\1
```

I want `\1` to be the first group of the search-regex.

This works in Python. How to do this in PyCharm?

Comment: Just use `$1` instead of `\1`